# chmod doesn't seem to work on Cygwin as expected

Tags: cygwin, chmod

I tried creating a file myFile and then typing
  chmod 000 myFile
just to see if I got access denied trying to cat it or open it with vi, but no, I could still do whatever I wanted with it. So what is it with chmod on cygwin?
Thanks!

Comment: On what system are you using cygwin?

Comment: Windows XP Professional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most restrictive permission that XP affords (for administrator accounts (which means most XP user)) is read-only or effective Unix mode 0444.

See [Why doesn't Cygwin chmod work](http://www.cygwin.com/faq/faq-nochunks.html#faq.using.chmod) and weep over [Using Windows security in Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html)

Comment: that's not really accurate; it's correct for FAT filesystems but most XP systems will be using NTFS.  NTFS ACLs aren't directly translatable to standard Unix permissions (tho Unix has a form of ACL as well).